# Setting Reminder/trigger alarm on user defined date and time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have trouble implementing Reminder for my app.i did research but couldnt find proper solution.
what i want is:

i am developing an android app which has one feature to remind users about the selected event 30 min before event start.

i will be displaying the date and time of the event in textview,on click of reminder button reminder will set 30min before event.
how can i proceed to implement this.

- Note: i dont want to use date/time picker, specific date and time will be taken directly from text view which i will display.

Any suggestion/links with logic please help.

- if any one can help dn please tell me the logic to add future,date + hours + minutes to current time to set alarm(date and time will be taken from textview)

Comment: what about going with alarm manager, for setting future tme.

Comment: yeah..ill be using alarm manager obviously but the problem is i want to fetch date and time from textview and write logic accordintly

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial and make necessary changes: http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Comment: if any one can help dn please tell me the logic to add future,date + hours + minutes to current time to set alarm(date and time will be taken from textview)

Comment: Assuming the schedule of the event was given, try:  `System.currentTimeMillis() + (scheduleOfTheEventInMilliseconds - 30*60*1000)`

Comment: please help me with "scheduleoftheeventinMill" part. suppose event is tomoro at 3rd nov , 4.15pm.